# Can i have a negative value as constant expression in Scala?

Tags: scala, annotations, constant-expression

I have an Java-Annotation that return a double value:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface DoubleValue {
  double value();
}
```

When i try to attach the annotation to a field in a scala class and the value is negativ like here:

```
class Test {
  @DoubleValue(-0.05)
  var a = _
}
```

i get an compiler error with the message: "annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: 0.05.unary_-". I understood that i need a numerical literal and i looked into the Scala Language Specification and it seems, that the - sign is only used for the exponent but not for the mantissa. Does someone has an idea how i can have a negative value as runtime information using annotations?

Thanks,
Klinke

Comment: It looks like you may have found the dark side of operators as methods. :)

Comment: Are you using Scala 2.7? Annotation handling in 2.8 is much improved.

Comment: *Update:* Apparently this "feature" remains in 2.8. I just tested it.

Comment: By the way, this is not a general issue of negative floating-point constants, just their use in annotation arguments. And integers are OK even now.

Comment: So, you've found a bug. I have entered it in the Scala bug database: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3521 - If you find bugs then please report them, otherwise the Scala developers won't know and the bug won't be fixed.

Comment: @Jasper: the Scala bug database itself says, "Are you certain it's a bug, and not simply your imperfect understanding of the language? If you have any doubt, please ask somewhere else before opening a ticket".

Comment: @Matt Yes but in this case it's quite clear that it's a bug.

Comment: @Jesper: (sorry about the above name typo). The problem is that sometimes things that seem to be obvious bugs turn out not to be, or are known and accepted limitations etc. I guess my point is that it's not really fair to give someone a hard time about asking on Stack Overflow first rather than immediately raising an issue -- particularly when that's what the Scala developers ask people to do.

Comment: @Matt It was not just meant for the original question asker, but also for Randall who I know knows quite a lot about Scala, and he knows that this is a bug. I agree that you should verify it first if you're not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug.

Until the bug is fixed, you can take advantage of the fact that arithmetic on a constant is a constant and use

```
@DoubleValue( 0-0.05 )
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and is a much better workaround then the "solution" i had in mind.